# Joins in Entity Framework need help

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have 3 Tables:

**Region**:

```
ID,
Name
```

**District**

```
ID,
RegionID,
Name
```

**City**

```
ID,
DistrictID,
Name
```

When I write like this:

```
var result = (from item in db.Region.Include("District.City")
              select item).ToList();
```

In result I have objects dependent on each other

For example: In `Region` I have 2 objects, in `District` 4 objects and in `City` 8 objects

I want to write this with Linq Join, not with `include()`

Can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

You can use join instead of include, but your relations won't change

```
var result = from r in db.Region
             join d in db.District on r.ID equals d.RegionID
             join c in db.City on d.ID equals c.DistrictID
             where r.ID == 1
             select r;
```

Comment: without Where parameter
when I write it like you with joins but without where it returns to result 8 Objects not 2

Comment: @west Sorry, just realized I forgot a select statement. You haven't actually defined how many results you're expecting. Are you expecting 1, 2, 4, 8? Just Region objects?

Comment: I expected 2 in Regions, when I write with Include() it works well and returns 2 Object in Region, 4 in District and 8 in City
but when i write with Join like you it returns 8 in Region

Comment: @west Can you update your OP to include exactly what you need your data to look like? I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you see My source I uploaded it it's simple project

[link](http://www.mediafire.com/?fjtqzdaeg6fd9wi)
@David